# Integrating Branch in Expo 49 Bare Workflow App

Tags: expo, deep-linking, branch.io

I am working on an Expo 49 Bare Workflow app and I'm currently facing challenges integrating Branch. Despite my efforts, I couldn't find many resources, documentation, or articles specifically addressing this integration in the Expo 49 Bare Workflow.

Could anyone please provide me with relevant links, documentation, or articles that could help me with this integration? Additionally, if you have personal experience or tips regarding integrating Branch in Expo 49 Bare Workflow, I would greatly appreciate any insights you can share.

What I've Tried:

```
npx expo install react-native-branch @config-plugins/react-native-branch
```

after installation i added the plugin to to the plugins in app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "plugins": ["@config-plugins/react-native-branch"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Branch generally don’t support Expo, since it hides early lifecycle methods which makes Branch compatibility difficult without ejecting the app. But additionally you can refer the readme file here: https://github.com/expo/config-plugins/tree/main/packages/react-native-branch?redirected

and also the issue raised here: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/6815